# ErrorException in Controller Argument 2 passed to Controller::__construct()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am getting this error in my laravel application I am not able to find a fix

```
ErrorException in FactoryController.php line 39:
Argument 2 passed to Vanguard\Http\Controllers\FactoryController::__construct() 
must implement interface Vanguard\Repositories\Factory\FactoryRepository, 
instance of Vanguard\Repositories\Country\EloquentCountry given
```

These are the lines that it is pointing to.

```
//Line 39 is below
public function __construct(CountryRepository $countries, FactoryRepository $factories, RoleRepository $roles, PermissionRepository $permissions)
{
    $this->middleware('permission:system.manage');
    $this->roles = $roles;
    $this->permissions = $permissions;
    $this->countries = $countries;
    $this->factories = $factories;

}
```

This is the code of FactoriesRepositories

```
   <?php

namespace Vanguard\Repositories\Factory;

interface FactoryRepository
{
    /**
     * Get all system factorys.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function all();

    /**
     * Finds the factory by given id.
     *
     * @param $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function find($id);

    /**
     * Creates new factory from provided data.
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(array $data);

    /**
     * Updates specified factory.
     *
     * @param $id
     * @param array $data
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update($id, array $data);

    /**
     * Remove specified factory from repository.
     *
     * @param $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete($id);
}
```

and this is the EloquentFactory

```
<?php

namespace Vanguard\Repositories\Factory;



use Cache;
use Vanguard\Events\Factory\Created;
use Vanguard\Events\Factory\Deleted;
use Vanguard\Events\Permission\Updated;
use Vanguard\Factories;

class EloquentFactory implements FactoryRepository
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function all()
    {
        return Factories::all();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function find($id)
    {
        return Factories::find($id);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function create(array $data)
    {
        $factory = Factories::create($data);

        event(new Created($factory));

        return $factory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function update($id, array $data)
    {
        $factory = $this->find($id);

        $factory->update($data);

        Cache::flush();

        event(new Updated($factory));

        return $factory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $factory = $this->find($id);

        event(new Deleted($factory));

        $status = $factory->delete();

        Cache::flush();

        return $status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel cannot create an instance from the type-hint FactoryRepository in the constructor. You need to bind a concrete instance to the interface so Laravel knows what to instantiate. Full details here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations

Answer (score 0):

From the given error, we knew that the `Vanguard\Repositories\Country\EloquentCountry` is not implementing the `Vanguard\Repositories\Factory\FactoryRepository` interface.

The possible workaround is to make sure that the `EloquentCountry` class implements the `FactoryRepository` interface by extending the base `EloquentFactory` class or by explicitly implementing the `FactoryRepository` interface.

Your `EloquentCountry` should be look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vanguard\Repositories\Country;

use Vanguard\Repositories\Factory\EloquentFactory;

class EloquentCountry extends EloquentFactory
{
    ...
}
```

And I believe you let the Laravel resolves `FactoryController` dependencies by itself. So, since you are type-hinting the `FactoryRepository` interface in the constructor and expecting the `EloquentCountry` implementation, you need to bind it within the container like so:

```
App::bind('Vanguard\Repositories\Factory\FactoryRepository', 'Vanguard\Repositories\Country\EloquentCountry');
```

Comment: why should `Vanguard\Repositories\Country\EloquentCountry ` implement  'Vanguard\Repositories\Factory\FactoryRepository'

Comment: Because in the second argument of `FactoryController` constructor, you are expecting that the `$factories` implements the `FactoryRepository` interface.

Answer (score 0):

adding `$this->app->singleton(FactoryRepository::class, EloquentFactory::class);`
 to `App\providers\AppServiceProvider.php` in register method solved the issue.

The following  error was my mistake

```
must implement interface Vanguard\Repositories\Factory\FactoryRepository, 
instance of Vanguard\Repositories\Country\EloquentCountry given
```

as I had by mistake added `$this->app->singleton(FactoryRepository::class, EloquentCountry ::class);`